# Sun Grid Engine : How to check the machine that a job was run on?

Tags: sungridengine, grid-computing

Is there a flag to make SGE output the machine that it finally dispatched a job to run on ? 
I looked through the man but couldn't pinpoint anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1: While the job is running, you could use `qstat -g t` to get the nodes, where your job(s) is/are running.

2: After the job has finished, `qacct -j [jobid]` shows information for each node, the job was running on.

3: On Linux you could execute the command `hostname` (or `mpirun hostname`) to print the respective nodes.